# Received SIGRTMIN+21 from PID ... (plymouthd)

Tags: crash, error-handling

Got a new crash report

Received SIGRTMIN+21 from PID ... (plymouthd).

What this error message is for and how to solve this?

Exact condition while playing online video via vlc.

Comment: Same here during startup on a Linux Mint laptop. Power off/on fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like in some cases this may be due to `/etc/fstab` corruption.

Related:

- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=832947
- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1254874
- [SIGRTMIN on plymouthd after switching from upstart to systemd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614622/sigrtmin-on-plymouthd-after-switching-from-upstart-to-systemd)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like in some cases it is due to the software, display card, or GPU failing to produce a graphical environment to login. In some cases this may mean that the message (as in the original post above) is not related to the issue observed (no graphical environment startup), i.e. the message is just displayed but otherwise unrelated to the observed issue, especially as it seems this SIGRTMIN+21 is supposed to happen.

Related:

- https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/plymouthd.8.html
- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=832947